# Crear columnas de forma dinámica en un DataTable C#

Tags: c#, webforms, datatable

Buen día, he estado intentando crear varias columnas de forma de dinámica para una DataTable(tableSumByCount), esto lo hago mediante un for y un parámetro periodo, la cual son la cantidad de columnas que deseo asignar al DataTable. Pero a partir del la línea (column[i].DataType = Type.GetType("System.Decimal"); ) me sale el error ($exception {"Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto."} System.NullReferenceException).

```
 DateTime fechaInicial = DateTime.Now;
 DataTable tableSumByCount = new DataTable();
 int frecuencia = int.Parse(Session["FCDFrecuencia"].ToString()); // 7 días
 int periodo = int.Parse(Session["FCDPeriodo"].ToString()); // Periodo es de 10
 int frecuenciaIncremetado = frecuencia;
 DataColumn[] column = new DataColumn[periodo];

        for (int i = 0; i < periodo; i++)
        {
            frecuenciaIncremetado += frecuencia;
            column[i].DataType = Type.GetType("System.Decimal");
            column[i].ColumnName = fechaInicial.AddDays(frecuenciaIncremetado - 1).ToShortDateString();
            tableSumByCount.Columns.Add(column[i]);
        }
```

Comment: ¿No deberías usar `System.Type.GetType("System.Decimal")` en vez de directamente `Type.GetType`?

Comment: Por otro lado, ¿para qué usar un array de DataColumn? Simplemente puedes crear cada columna dentro del loop `for`.

Comment: Agregar el "System" es innecesario, ya que, ya tengo referenciado "using System;" y lo del array es para evitar el error de que la columna column ya pertenece en la tabla.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que column[i] no está inicializado. Al crear un array, no se crean automáticamente los elementos de ese array. Deberías hacer algo así:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < periodo; i++)
    {
        frecuenciaIncremetado += frecuencia;
        String columnName = fechaInicial.AddDays(frecuenciaIncremetado - 1).ToShortDateString();
        Type columnType = Type.GetType("System.Decimal");

        column[i] = new DataColumn(columnName, columnType);           
        tableSumByCount.Columns.Add(column[i]);
    }
```

O directamente:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < periodo; i++)
    {
        frecuenciaIncremetado += frecuencia;
        String columnName = fechaInicial.AddDays(frecuenciaIncremetado - 1).ToShortDateString();
        Type columnType = Type.GetType("System.Decimal");                      
        tableSumByCount.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(columnName, columnType));
    }
```

Comment: Vaya! lo he probado y sí que funciona, muchas gracias Federico, tenías razón trabajándolo de esta forma es innecesario usar el array.